# Not able to edit/manage connected app deployed through trialforce template

Tags: connected-apps, trialforce

I am getting issue with "Connected App" in free trial org created from TSO(trialforce template).

**Scenario:** I have configured the connected apps in my TSO org to configure my application. I created a trialforce template from TSO to create new free trial/demo org, it is created successfully, all the configurations are also fine except the connected apps.

When I am trying to edit or manage the connected app in a new free trial/demo org getting "Internal Server Error".

Can some one help me, how can I clone connected apps using trialforce template or is there something which I am missing.

Comment: Internal errors need Salesforce support investigation. Hope you start the process soon.

Comment: Are you seeing [GACK Id](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/tag/gack) along with the internal server error?

Comment: Looks related to [known issue](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?&Id=a1p300000010wE5)

Comment: @MohithShrivastava Correct, checking with SF as well.